# Query Linkedin API to receive all CampaignGroups of a given AdAccount

Tags: ads, linkedin-api

I use the latest (april 2023) version of Linkedin API as versioned version.

I successfully do the oauth and I can search for the AdAccounts related to the authenticated user. I can get all campaigns and I can get all campaignGroups of the authenticated user.

e.g. this REST call works fine:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search=(status:(values:List(ACTIVE,DRAFT,PAUSED)))&sort=(field:ID,order:ASCENDING)

But I want to search for campaignGroups that are related to a given AdAccount only. That does not work properly. I receive an error message

I want to search for campaignGroups that are related to a given AdAccount only. I my example adAccount with ID 11111111.

I tried this:

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search=(account:(values:List(urn:li:sponsoredAccount:11111111)))&sort=(field:ID,order:ASCENDING)

I receive an error message:
{'status': 400, 'code': 'ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT', 'message': 'Invalid query parameters passed to request'}

Search is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaign-groups?view=li-lms-2023-04&tabs=http#search-for-campaign-groups

Any idea on this?

thanks
Niko

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue... It seems that LinkedIn is a bit sloppy with the way they accept the query parameter for the URN.

For example, as you mentioned, the following Request will result in a 400 response:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search=(account:(values:List(urn:li:sponsoredAccount:11111111)))&sort=(field:ID,order:ASCENDING)
```

Try replacing the ':' of the URN with the base 64 encoded variant '%3A'. The request would look as follows:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search=(account:(values:List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A11111111)))&sort=(field:ID,order:ASCENDING)
```

Comment: `%3A` is [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), not base 64.